# Por que o SOpt não tem o Careers?

Tags: novo-recurso, careers

A pergunta é bem simples e direta:

Por que nosso SOpt não tem o [*Careers*](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Como assim Wallace?

Comment: @JorgeB. Veja a minha edição.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Antes de qualquer coisa, uma breve explicação do que é o [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com):

O Careers é um "classificado" de empregos para programadores, integrado com seu perfil do Stack Overflow em inglês. Funciona normalmente como os outros sites de emprego (as empresas colocam suas vagas, os programadores se candidatam), mas com o diferencial de que tentamos ao máximo só indicar empregos que realmente sejam atraentes. Como a gente faz isso é segredo!

O Careers existe em inglês, alemão e francês. Ou seja: 2 línguas que sequer tem Stack Overflow. A diferença se dá porque os requisitos para abrir um Careers e um Stack Overflow são diferentes.

Um Stack Overflow depende de um língua com um grande número de programadores, que sejam bastante ativos, e em que grande parte deles não fale inglês.
O Careers depende de um mercado de trabalho de tecnologia capaz de sustentar o investimento e manter o site ativo, além de um grande número de programadores (obviamente)

Abrir um Careers é consideravelmente mais trabalhoso que um Stack Overflow. É preciso abrir uma empresa no país, contratar uma equipe de vendas, captar clientes. É uma operação bem mais complicada.

Eu não sei se o Brasil, ou Portugal (ou ambos) vão ter seus Careers. É bastante provável que sim, mas no momento o melhor é procurar vagas no Brasil no Careers em inglês. Existem [algumas](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Brazil).

Answer (score 5):

Apesar da resposta já dada pelo [@Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4188/3635), eu tenho uma visão diferente, o uso do nome *stackoverflow* no Careers é devido a 3 fatores:

1. Popularidade do SOen
2. Na época que foi criado o Careers ainda não existia SOpt, SOja e SOru.
3. O publico alvo do Careers são os desenvolvedores, no entanto eventualmente ele "aceita" outros tipos de "empregos"

Eu posso estar enganado, mas até aonde entendo do Careers, ele suporta qualquer site da rede do StackExchange (isto não quer dizer que haverá empregos pra estas outras áreas, como askubuntu ou Coffee.SE).

Veja o meu perfil por exemplo http://careers.stackoverflow.com/brcontainer todas a maior parte das *"respostas"* são do SOpt e não do SOen.

Note que no perfil do Careers também aparece todas contas (você escolhe quais aparecem):

[image: Contas no Careers]

Outro detalhe importante é que no perfil do SOpt (e de qualquer site da rede) também exibir um botão/link pro seu Careers, veja um exemplo no meu perfil:

[image: Link para o Careers]

ou seja eu acredito que o Careers serve pra qualquer site da rede e funciona a nível internacional e devido a este motivo não acredito que não haverá *outros Careers*.

Então qualquer site da rede "tem" o Careers.

### Opinião pessoal

Acho que algo que falta nos sites que "prestam serviços" para empresas no caso do SE seria o Careers, seria uma internacionalização melhor, por exemplo suporte a um estrutura "i8n", assim empresas de outros países poderia ter melhor acesso as ferramentas. Mas eu realmente não posso discutir sobre isto, pois não entendo muito de mercado, nem de como funciona o mercado de tecnologia para quem trabalha com "mão de obra internacional" e também não sei como é a estrutura tecnológica do Careers que limita isto.

### Nota

> Eu acho que a pergunta era sobre um Careers em português, ou voltado para o mercado brasileiro. Como o Gabe disse, existem outros Careers, voltados para os mercados francês e alemão - [@bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4187/por-que-o-sopt-n%C3%A3o-tem-o-careers#comment11817_4189)

Apenas para deixar claro a diferença, o autor perguntou do *SOpt* para *Careers* e não do *mercado brasileiro em si*, o que dá a entender que o autor entende que o careers.stackoverflow.com pertence exclusivamente ao stackoverflow.com, mas como respondi acima, o uso do nome stackoverflow provavelmente é devido aos 3 fatores já citados.

No entanto **se a pergunta fosse:**

> Por que não temos uma cidade brasileira no http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities?

Então eu concordaria com a [resposta do @Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4188/3635), não que eu discorde, pelo contrario concordo com a resposta completamente, só acho que a maioria das pessoas pensam que o Careers pertence apenas ao SOen (assim como parece ser a duvida discutida aqui), o que não é verdade e é isto que a minha resposta tenta esclarecer.

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta era sobre um Careers *em português*, ou voltado para o mercado brasileiro. Como o Gabe disse, existem outros Careers, voltados para os mercados francês e alemão.

Comment: @bfavaretto Entendo, mas acho realmente que a duvida é em relação ao SOpt e não as "localizações", gostaria que olha-se a minha atualização a resposta, espero que compreenda o porque da minha resposta e não leve mal :)

Comment: Eu não levo a mal não :) É que no SO (en) tem um link pro Careers lá no topo, no menu "Stack Exchange". No SOpt não tem, e isso porque o público aqui é diferente. Nosso site é todo em português, e o Careers não, então esse link (um "Careers do SOpt") não faz sentido – mesmo havendo cidades e empresas brasileiras (e possivelmente portuguesas) no Careers. Não é bem uma questão conceitual ("a quem pertence o Careers?"), e sim de marketing, como você mostrou na sua resposta, principalmente pela popularidade do SOen.